# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'column'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lowercase

I'm trying to retrieve the column names of a dataframe, all in lower case, but that's giving me the following **Attribute Error: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'column'**.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('C:/dataset.csv')

col_names=df.column.values.lower()
print(col_names)
```

Why is this error showing up & how do I fix it?

Comment: Use df.columns instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, replace "column" by "columns" and use the [`str.lower`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.lower.html) accessor:

```
col_names = df.columns.str.lower().tolist()
```